# Python open() raises an error if I try to create a file

Tags: python, file, io

I'm having a problem with Python 2.6 on windows.
Whether I try:

```
fileobj=open("nonexistent.txt","w")
```

or

```
fil=os.open("nonexistent.txt", os.O_CREAT)
fileobj=file(fil)
```

I get an error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nonexistent.txt'

What may be the problem?

Comment: How can you expect a useful answer if you provide misleading information about your problem, i. e. if you don't provide the actual code triggering the error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will not be able to read the file if it does not exist, however, you should be able to write to it.  Does the code below return the same error?

```
f=open("nonexistent.txt","w")
f.write('Test')
f.close()
```

Comment: also you can use `print >>f, 'Test'`

Answer (score -1):

At seems like a permission problem.
Try opening the file somewhere else or run the python as an Administrator.